# Как в цикле произвести сравнение дат? Python

Tags: python, datetime

Есть список с данными записей. В каждой записи, которая также является списком, есть строковая переменная date. Необходимо перебрать записи и выбрать те, которые создались за последнюю неделю. При сравнении с операторами <> не происходит результата, а при сравнении с оператором ==, условие срабатывает. Помогите, пожалуйста. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
import datetime as dt

class Records: # Описываем класс для создания записей
    def __init__(self, amount, comment, date):
        self.amount = amount
        self.comment = comment
        self.date = date

r1 = Records(amount=124, comment='text', date='28.04.2020')
r2 = Records(amount=234, comment='text', date='29.04.2020')
r3 = Records(amount=144, comment='text', date='30.04.2020')
r4 = Records(amount=1334, comment='text', date='01.05.2020')
r5 = Records(amount=1334, comment='text', date='02.05.2020')
r6 = Records(amount=114, comment='text', date='03.05.2020')
r7 = Records(amount=1774, comment='text', date='04.05.2020')
r8 = Records(amount=136, comment='text', date='05.05.2020')

record = [] # Создаем список для хранения записей
def add_record(records):
    temp_list = []
    temp_list.append(records.amount)
    temp_list.append(records.comment)
    temp_list.append(records.date)
    record.append(temp_list)
    #print(record)
add_record(r1)
add_record(r2)
add_record(r3)
add_record(r4)
add_record(r5)
add_record(r6)
add_record(r7)
add_record(r8)

#n = (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=6)).date().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
#print(n)
#if record[0][2] < n:
#    print(record[0][2])


#Цикл для нахождения суммы amount за неделю
sum1 = 0
n1 = (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=6)).date().strftime('%d.%m.%Y') #Сегодняшняя дата минус 6 дней (начало недели)
n2 = dt.datetime.now().date().strftime('%d.%m.%Y') #Сегодняшняя дата
#print(n1, n2)
for i in record:
    if i[2] > n1 and i[2] <= n2:
        print(i[2])
        sum1 += i[0]
```

Comment: > при сравнении с оператором ==, условие срабатывает 

Вам же вроде и нужно, чтобы условие срабатывало, когда даты равны

Answer (score 0):

Вы сравниваете строки, а не даты. Делайте так:

```
import datetime as dt

class Records: # Описываем класс для создания записей
    def __init__(self, amount, comment, date):
        self.amount = amount
        self.comment = comment
        self.date = date

r1 = Records(amount=124, comment='text', date='28.04.2020')
r2 = Records(amount=234, comment='text', date='29.04.2020')
r3 = Records(amount=144, comment='text', date='30.04.2020')
r4 = Records(amount=1334, comment='text', date='01.05.2020')
r5 = Records(amount=1334, comment='text', date='02.05.2020')
r6 = Records(amount=114, comment='text', date='03.05.2020')
r7 = Records(amount=1774, comment='text', date='04.05.2020')
r8 = Records(amount=136, comment='text', date='05.05.2020')

record = [] # Создаем список для хранения записей
def add_record(records):
    temp_list = []
    temp_list.append(records.amount)
    temp_list.append(records.comment)
    temp_list.append(dt.datetime.strptime(records.date, '%d.%m.%Y').date())
    record.append(temp_list)
    #print(record)
add_record(r1)
add_record(r2)
add_record(r3)
add_record(r4)
add_record(r5)
add_record(r6)
add_record(r7)
add_record(r8)

#Цикл для нахождения суммы amount за неделю
sum1 = 0
n1 = (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=6)).date() #Сегодняшняя дата минус 6 дней (начало недели)
n2 = dt.datetime.now().date() #Сегодняшняя дата
for i in record:
    if i[2] > n1 and i[2] <= n2:
        print(i[2])
        sum1 += i[0]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Проблема решена!

Comment: Примите ответ (зелёная галочка слева), если он вам помог.